# How to replace Spring ApplicationContext in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

In an old spring application, I have the following in the applicationContext.xml file, now I need to rewrite it in Spring Boot?
How do I do that in Spring Boot?
Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it?

Spring applicationContext.xml

```xml
<bean id="dealTicketDAO" class="SqlMapDealTicketDAO">
    <property name="dealTicketMapper" ref="dealTicketMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="dealTicketMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="DealTicketMapper"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dealTicketService" parent="baseTransactionProxy">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="DealTicketServiceImpl">
            <property name="dealTicketDAO">
                <ref local="dealTicketDAO"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class annotated with @Configuration
the dependency is `(org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration)`

and for each bean declaration in your XML file create a @Bean (org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean) method within this class.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
@Bean
  public MapperFactoryBean<DealTicketMapper> dealTicketMapper() throws Exception {
    MapperFactoryBean<DealTicketMapper> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(DealTicketMapper.class);
    factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory());
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public DealTicketService dealTicketService(DealTicketDAO dealTicketDAO){
return new DealTicketServiceImpl(dealTicketDAO);
}
```

this should surely help you